# Form the oxides of the element Z=39

Tags: electronic-configuration

Its electronic configuration is $4d^15s^2$ so in normal state it has valence=1 and in energetic state, valence=2 (because our teacher said we count only the electrons in the outer shell firstly) and valence =3. First question: is it true what my teacher said? It was for Z=22 example, where she said it has the valence 2 and  4). Second question **when we form the oxide we should use only the valence in the energetic states and not the one in the normal state?**

Comment: No one looks at the periodic table through the lens of Z.  This assignment is ... dumb.

Comment: Z=38 is Sr, isn't it, and the electronic configuration is 4d0 5s2.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that I understand your question, but in terms of establishing the valency in this case the key point is that in d block elements the energy level of the outer s electrons are very similar to that of the d electrons in the shell below, so the valency in this case will be 3.